# iOS 8.0 NSAttributedString init with HTML file crashes

Tags: html, ios8, initialization, nsattributedstring

I am trying to initialize an attributed string with HTML file contents, as following:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:chapterPath]
                                                                         options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
                                                              documentAttributes:nil error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

and it does work with iOS7.1 and iOS8.1 and up, but something goes wrong with iOS8.0:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector

Is this initialization method broken in iOS8.0? Any workaround? 
BTW, I have tried to parse an RTF file and, with iOS8.0, it fails to collect any font information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:chapterPath options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: data options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:&attributes error:nil];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot test it - the device was updated; and there is no iOS8.0 simulator. But I did try the following: "NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:chapterPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];" and the file was read just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Init with HTML for `NSAttributedString` is on main thread only. If you doing that in background be ready to crash.

Comment: Following the discussion below, better to @try-catch that block. And iOS 8 is nowadays pretty rare (fuf). Hope ios 8.1 will go soon as well